# What is happening to memory when I do this?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, uiimage

I am trying to figure out how to pass a UIImage around between various view controllers without duplicating the UIImage and increasing memory unnecessarily. The image is passed successfully using the method below, but I cannot seem to free up this UIImage later on, which ends up weighing down my app with 7MB+ of data that cannot be accounted for. What I want to know is, what is happening to memory when I pass a UIImage (belonging to my current view controller) to a view controller I will be switching to next, and then release the original pointer? Like this:

```
-(IBAction)startEditing:(id)sender
{

    EditViewController *controller = [[EditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

            //imageDataPhoto1 is of type UIImage (from camera)
            controller.editPhotoData1 = imageDataPhoto1;
            [imageDataPhoto1 release];
            imageDataPhoto1 = nil;

        controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];

}
```

is the DATA of the pointer *imageDataPhoto1* not getting released due to it being assigned to the view controller instance before it is released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `EditViewController`'s .h file declares the `editPhotoData1` `@property` with `retain`, then it will automatically retain any object assigned to it. You'll need to `release` the object explicitly, at the very least ,in `EditViewController`'s `dealloc` method.

As a matter of course, you should make sure to `release` any properties set to retain in your dealloc method, for all classes, i.e.:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [editPhotoData1 release];
    ...
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read up on UIImage.  It does a lot of caching and reloading behind-the-scenes, especially if it gets its pictures from a named file or path.  I don't think that duplicating an instance actually creates a second copy.  See the description of +imageNamed and others to see what I am talking about:

> ### imageNamed:
>
> Returns the image object associated
>   with the specified filename.
>
> > - (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name
>
> ### Parameters
>
> name The name of the file, including
>   its filename extension. If this is the
>   first time the image is being loaded,
>   the method looks for an image with the
>   specified name in the application’s
>   main bundle.
>
> ### Return Value
>
> The image object for the specified
>   file, or nil if the method could not
>   find the specified image.
>
> ### Discussion
>
> This method looks in the system caches
>   for an image object with the specified
>   name and returns that object if it
>   exists. If a matching image object is
>   not already in the cache, this method
>   loads the image data from the
>   specified file, caches it, and then
>   returns the resulting object.